# global не работает в GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Я получаю ошибку:

> global self.text 
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Как заставить `global` работать с `self.text`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.text=''
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(503, 450)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 21, 21))
        self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
        self.b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 21, 21))
        self.b4.setObjectName("b4")
        self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 21, 21))
        self.b3.setObjectName("b3")
        self.b5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 21, 21))
        self.b5.setObjectName("b5")
        self.b6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 21, 21))
        self.b6.setObjectName("b6")
        self.b7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 21, 21))
        self.b7.setObjectName("b7")
        self.b8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 21, 21))
        self.b8.setObjectName("b8")
        self.b9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 21, 21))
        self.b9.setObjectName("b9")
        self.back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 21, 21))
        self.back.setObjectName("back")
        self.b0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 21, 21))
        self.b0.setObjectName("b0")
        self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 21, 21))
        self.ok.setObjectName("ok")
        self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 21, 21))
        self.b2.setObjectName("b2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 61, 16))
        self.label.setText(self.text)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.add()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.b1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.b4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.b3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.b5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.b6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.b7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.b8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.b9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.back.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.b0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.ok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.b2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))

    def add(self):
        self.b1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('1'))
        self.b2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('2'))
        self.b3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('3'))
        self.b4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('4'))
        self.b5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('5'))
        self.b6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('6'))
        self.b7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('7'))
        self.b8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('8'))
        self.b9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('9'))
        self.b0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('0'))
        self.ok.clicked.connect(lambda: self.o())

    def write(self,arg):
        global self.text
        self.text+arg
        self.label.setText(self.label.setText(self.text))

    def o(self):
        print(self.text)
        if self.label.text() == '1295':
            self.label.setText('ok')
        else:
            self.label.setText('error')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: если в вашем коде есть global, то что-то пошло не так и вы свернули на кривую дорожку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`, **НИКОГДА**. Создайте другой класс,
   который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
2. Забудьте про `global`.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
#        self.text=''
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(503, 450)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 21, 21))
        self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
        self.b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 21, 21))
        self.b4.setObjectName("b4")
        self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 21, 21))
        self.b3.setObjectName("b3")
        self.b5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 21, 21))
        self.b5.setObjectName("b5")
        self.b6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 21, 21))
        self.b6.setObjectName("b6")
        self.b7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 21, 21))
        self.b7.setObjectName("b7")
        self.b8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 21, 21))
        self.b8.setObjectName("b8")
        self.b9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 21, 21))
        self.b9.setObjectName("b9")
        self.back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 21, 21))
        self.back.setObjectName("back")
        self.b0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 21, 21))
        self.b0.setObjectName("b0")
        self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 80, 21, 21))
        self.ok.setObjectName("ok")
        self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 21, 21))
        self.b2.setObjectName("b2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 61, 16))
        self.label.setText("") # (self.text)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
#        self.add()
        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.b1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.b4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.b3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.b5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.b6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.b7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.b8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.b9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.back.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.b0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.ok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.b2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.text = ''
        self.add()

    def add(self):
        self.b1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('1'))
        self.b2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('2'))
        self.b3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('3'))
        self.b4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('4'))
        self.b5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('5'))
        self.b6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('6'))
        self.b7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('7'))
        self.b8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('8'))
        self.b9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('9'))
        self.b0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write('0'))
        self.ok.clicked.connect(lambda: self.o())
        
    def write(self, arg):
#        global self.text
        text = self.text + arg
#        self.label.setText(self.label.setText(self.text))
        self.label.setText(self.label.text() + text)
        
    def o(self):
        print(self.text)
        if self.label.text() == '1295':
            self.label.setText('ok')
        else:
            self.label.setText('error') 
            
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.label.clear)
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]